# How to install MySQL server in Raspbian Stretch

Tags: mysql, linux, raspbian

I am a bit desperate. I've tried to install mysql in Raspbian Strectch but I get instead mariadb.

I've followed this tutorial step by step but I still get mariadb installed.

https://dbahire.com/how-to-install-mysql-server-on-debian-stretch/

> pi@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo mysql -u root
>
> Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>
> Your MariaDB connection id is 4
>
> Server version: 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 Raspbian 9.0
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input  statement.
>
> MariaDB [(none)]>

What can I do?

Comment: using mariadb..

Comment: That guide, right at the top, states "In the latest stable version of Debian, if you ask to install mysql-server, you now get installed mariadb automatically, with no (evident) way of installing Oracle’s MySQL." Did you follow the first few lines or the bit after that statement that shows how to get mysql itself installed?

Answer (score -3):

Why do you want MySQL over MariaDB?  They are largely interchangeable so you can probably just use MariaDB, most MySQL things work well with it.